# How to send wrapped json request

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

Hi I am trying to send a request to following contract:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UpdateString/{stringlength}?stringid=     {stringid}",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[Description("Updates String")]
public string UpdateString(long stringid, string stringlength, string newstring)
{
  return code.UpdateString( stringid, stringlength,  newstring);
}
```

The code within the Silverlight Application to the send the request is as follows:

```
SendNewString = "This is my new string"
public void UpdateString()
{
  WebRequest client = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(_baseUrl));
  client.Method = "POST";
  client.ContentType = HttpContentType;
  client.BeginGetRequestStream(UpdateStringRequestProceed, client);
}

private void UpdateStringRequestProceed(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
  var request = (HttpWebRequest) asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
  request.Accept = HttpContentType;

  using (Stream requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult))
  {
    using (StreamWriter postDataWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
    {
      DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(object));
                ser.WriteObject(postDataWriter.BaseStream,                                                                           SendNewString);
    }
 }
```

}

Original this worked when the WebMessageBodyStyle was set to Bare, but now it is a WrappedRequest. Looking in Fiddler I get the error message:

```
"Message":"OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find an     attribute with name 'type' and value 'object'. Found value 'string'."}
```

So my question is how do you wrap a json request?

THE WAY ROUND THIS:

```
postDataWriter.Write(string.Format("{{\"message\":\"{0}\", \"stringid\":\"{1}\"}}",       SendNewString, stringid));
```

Answer (score 0):

With POST action we cannot have query string as part of the URI. In order to post a request to the above method the request needs to look as shown below:

```
POST  http://localhost/VDName/Service.svc/rest/UpdateString HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json

{"stringid":5, "stringlength":"5","newstring":"5"}
```